# Stale Element error after a specific element in a list

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to get the tyres' details from this page. https://eurawheels.com/fr/catalogue/BBS

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-1 col-md-3"]//a')
parent_window = driver.current_window_handle
x = 0
for j in range(len(links)):
    driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', links[j])
    #scraping here
    if x == 0:
       driver.close()
       driver.switch_to.window(parent_window)
       x += 1
    else:
        driver.back()
    driver.refresh() #refresh page
    tyres = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="card-body text-center"]//a'))) #redefine links
    time.sleep(4)
```

It works for 10 links but then the links go stale. Cannot figure out what needs to be changed. Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is it you are trying to scrape from details pages?

Comment: everything there.

Comment: I asked you that question only to know whether I understood what you meant by the details page. However, you seem to be in a real hurry. Thanks.

Comment: links[j] returns a webelement how are you opening the new window its should n't work at all

Comment: @PDHide It works. Only issue is the stale element. The website is a bit weird as well. The page cannot go back, so I had to make do, however I could.

Comment: How it works , what does it opens ? it should throw exception saying in valid url .

Comment: It works because the click is a function not a url. Check the source if possible for you.

Comment: @PDHide Can you please take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67486068/how-to-fix-stale-element-error-without-refreshing-the-page

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `scroll element into the view` before executing `driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', links[j])` since not all the elements are initially loaded on the page.
So your code should look like following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-1 col-md-3"]//a')
parent_window = driver.current_window_handle
x = 0
for j in range(len(links)):
    actions.move_to_element(j).perform()
    driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', links[j])
    #scraping here
    if x == 0:
       driver.close()
       driver.switch_to.window(parent_window)
       x += 1
    else:
        driver.back()
    driver.refresh() #refresh page
    tyres = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="card-body text-center"]//a'))) #redefine links
    time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: let me give that a try.    `raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement")
AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement`

Comment: It should be `actions.move_to_element(links[j])` ..I think.Trying that

Comment: So, did `move_to_element` in this or that way solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://eurawheels.com/fr/catalogue/BBS'

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)
    driver.get(link)

    linklist = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".card-body > a")))
    for i,elem in enumerate(linklist):
        linklist[i].click()
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".spinner-border[role='status']")))
        time.sleep(2) #if you kick out this delay, your script will run very fast but you may end up getting same results multiple times.
        item = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h3"))).text
        print(item)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.modal-title + button[class='close'][data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
        driver.back()
```

Comment: Did you try the script @Abhishek Rai? What's the feedback?