# How to fix stale element error without refreshing the page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to get details of Tyres on this page. https://eurawheels.com/fr/catalogue/INFINY-INDIVIDUAL . Each tyre has different **FINITIONS**. The price and other details are different for each FINITIONS. I would like to click on each FINITION type. The problem is that on clicking the FINITION type the links go stale, and You cannot refresh the page, if you do it will take you back to the starting page. So, How can I avoid stale element error without refreshing the page?

```
     count_added = False
     buttons_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn-group"]')
     fin_buttons = buttons_div[2].find_elements_by_xpath('.//button')
     fin_count = len(fin_buttons) 
     if fin_count > 2:
            for z in range(fin_count):
                if not count_added:
                    z = z + 2 #Avoid clicking the Title
                    count_added = True
                fin_buttons[z].click()
                finition = fin_buttons[z].text
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.refresh() #Cannot do this. Will take to a different page
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: the stale element is thrown because the element is no longer attached to the DOM. In your case is this: buttons_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn-group"]') that its being used as parent in the fin_buttons[z].click()

To solve this you'll have to "refresh" the element once the DOM changes. You can do that like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://eurawheels.com/fr/catalogue/INFINY-INDIVIDUAL")

driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='card-body text-center']/a")[1].click()


def click_fin_buttons(index):
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn-group"]')[2].find_elements_by_xpath('.//button')[index].click()

def text_fin_buttons(index):
    return driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn-group"]')[2].find_elements_by_xpath('.//button')[index].text

sleep(2)
count_added = False
buttons_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn-group"]')
fin_buttons = buttons_div[2].find_elements_by_xpath('.//button')
fin_count = len(fin_buttons) 
if fin_count > 2:
    for z in range(fin_count):
        if not count_added:
            z = z + 2 #Avoid clicking the Title
            count_added = True
        click_fin_buttons(z)
        finition = text_fin_buttons(z)
        sleep(2)
        print(finition)
        #driver.refresh() #Cannot do this. Will take to a different page
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still gives the stale element exception. Where exactly are you refreshing the element here?

Comment: Hmm weird, on my side its clicking on all FINITION without stale element. Here its refreshing the FINITIONs: click_fin_buttons(z) and to get the text text_fin_buttons(z)